# Crystal report doesn't displayed after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, crystal-reports

I've created a crystal report and it works on my production server but after deployment the report doesn't display in web page. When I view the page's source I can see report data as html elements. My production server is x32 and deployment server is x64.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store crystalrportiewer related css, js etc. into:

aspnet_client -> system_web folder.[image]

Comment: there are all files. I created a folder 4_0_30319 and copeid crstalreportviewer13 there.

Comment: can you please restart server and then try once.

Comment: I restarted and nothing happened.